How to parse xml file with Logstash and store values into ElasticSearch?
I'm a beginner in Logstash and I'd like to store rows from a database into an ES index and parse a XML file to add missing fields.
Here is the logstash.conf:
# Sample Logstash configuration for creating a simple
# Beats -> Logstash -> Elasticsearch pipeline.

input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }

  tcp {
    port => 50000
  }

  jdbc {
      jdbc_driver_library => "sqlite-jdbc-3.6.7.jar"
      jdbc_driver_class => "org.sqlite.JDBC"
      jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlite:products.db"
      jdbc_user => ""
      jdbc_password => ""
      statement => "SELECT * FROM products"
  }

  file {
      path => "stocks.xml"
      start_position => "beginning"
      sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
      codec => multiline {
        pattern => "^<product>"
        negate => true
        what => "previous"
      }
  }
}

filter {
  xml {
    source => "message"
    target => "parsed_xml"
    store_xml => false
    xpath => [
      "//product/productid/text()", "product_id",
      "//product/quantity/text()", "quantity"
    ]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "products"
    document_id => "%{id}"
  }
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}


and the XML file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<stock>
    <product>
        <productid>1</productid>
        <quantity>87</quantity>
    </product>
    <product>
        <productid>2</productid>
        <quantity>54</quantity>
    </product>
    <product>
        <productid>3</productid>
        <quantity>24</quantity>
    </product>
    <product>
        <productid>4</productid>
        <quantity>13</quantity>
    </product>
    <product>
        <productid>5</productid>
        <quantity>22</quantity>
    </product>
</stock>

The "products" table has 4 fields: ID, name, description and price. With the XML file, we have the quantity of each product (the productid attribute corresponds to the ID in the database.
I'm using Logstash 8.7 and ES 8.7.
For the moment, the quantities aren't stored in the index and I don't know why.
I've also tried, unsuccessfully
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }

  tcp {
    port => 50000
  }

  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "sqlite-jdbc-3.6.7.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "org.sqlite.JDBC"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlite:products.db"
    jdbc_user => ""
    jdbc_password => ""
    statement => "SELECT * FROM products"
  }

  file {
    path => "stocks.xml"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    codec => multiline {
      pattern => "<product>"
      negate => true
      what => "previous"
    }
  }
}

filter {
  xml {
    source => "message"
    target => "parsed_xml"
    store_xml => false
    force_array => false
    xpath => [
      "//product/productid/text()", "product_id",
      "//product/quantity/text()", "quantity"
    ]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "products"
    document_id => "%{id}"
  }
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}

Do you have any idea?
Thanks a lot!

pattern => "^<product>"

Your file does not contain any lines that match this pattern, so the multiline codec on the file input will consume the entire file and then wait forever for a line that does match.
You could set the auto_flush_interval on the codec to consume the entire file as one event, or you could change the pattern to "<product>".
You might want to add force_array => false to the xml options.
